# PHP or Java Confirm if user has access to a specific folder on a network drive

Tags: java, php, directory

When the user goes to a specific page on an internal network website I need to check if they user has access to a very specific network folder. I need something that operates like is_readable() but from the users system perspective and not from the server.

Basically if you have network priviledges to access a special folder then the site is accessable. If not you are denied access. It's a quick and dirty way to avoid a user login system. It piggy backs on the networks security without actually integrating with it.

I don't mind doing this in PHP or Java. Any ideas?

Comment: Not that i know of... but is there a problem with putting the users in a LDAP security group and  querying that to determine if they have access? I find it's usually better (stabler) to do things the right way than the quick and dirty way.

Comment: Users are already in LDAP groups but I wont have access to query the LDAP server :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be done with [jcifs](http://jcifs.samba.org/), but you may need the password of the user.

Is a windows oder unix filesystem?

For windows you may call `cacls c:\path` and parse the output for the usersname. But this is some kind of ugly.

Comment: The user will be running Windows systems. The server is run on Windows 2008 Server - Apache.

Comment: I see. Calling cacls on a directory that a user doesn't have access to returns "Access is denied.". But how would I call this windows file and parse the return in PHP from the users system and not the server?